# Как наложить текст на картинку?

Tags: wordpress, css, javascript

Есть у меня вот такое решение:

```
<article>
        <div class="imgteaser">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?> 
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail'); ?></a>  
                <?php } ?>
                <figcaption>
                    <strong><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></strong>
                    <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                </figcaption>
        </div>
</article>

.imgteaser { /* общий блок */
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 0;
  color: rgb(223,223,223);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.imgteaser:after { /* "подробнее" */
  content: "подробнее \bb";
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: rgba(17,34,51,.6);
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
.imgteaser:hover:after {content: none;}

.imgteaser figcaption {display: none;}
.imgteaser:hover figcaption { /* прозрачная область */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: rgba(68,85,102,.7);
  font-size: 80%;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

.imgteaser:hover figcaption strong { /* заголовок */
  display: block;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 110%;
}
```

Вот скриншот:

[image]

А так при наведении:

[image]

Собственно, хотелось бы, чтобы было не "подробнее", а заголовок. Может кто-то помочь подправить css? Или если нельзя на css, то может кто-то помочь скриптом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dbry1v91/